# Join function is not returning a string value from a list

Tags: python, list, join

I am trying to make convert a list into a string so i can print it and show my desired outcome however, for some reason, the join function is not working like it was before.

This is my code:

```
xno = 5
yno = 10

exis =xno*'x'


list1 = ('.',exis,'-')*yno
str1 = ''.join(list1)
strop = str(str1)



flist = strop.split('-')




'\n'.join(flist)

print(flist)
```

Comment: You need to assign the result to something, like `flist = '\n'.join(flist)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, `join` will return a new value but won't modify the list reference passed in.

You could set a variable as such:

```
list_str = '\n'.join(flist)

print(list_str)
```

or, just pass the `join` function into `print`:

```
print('\n'.join(flist))
```